# How can I opt out 'Transparency Shapes Layer' in Photoshop via Jsx

Tags: jsx, photoshop

I believe I can do it with the JSX calling an Action script, but I think that would be more efficient if I could directly do with via the JSX. Unfortutanatelly I can't find anything about this option in the JavaScript Scripting Reference pdf from Adobe...

[this option here :"Transparency Shapes Layer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS1W9.png)

So far I have this, the idea being to check if a Layer is in LinearDodge mode and if so to uncheck "Transparency Shapes Layer" 

(Im a newbie so this was for testing purpose):

```
var doc= app.activeDocument;

for (i=0 ; i < doc.layers.length; i++) {
if (doc.layers[i].blendMode == BlendMode.LINEARDODGE) {
        //alert ('found it');
        //doc.layers[i].blendMode = BlendMode.MULTIPLY;
        //doc.activeLayer=doc.layers[i];
          }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe by saying Action Script you mean Action Manager Code and by JSX you mean Photoshop DOM? Anyway Action Manager code is usually more efficient than DOM (up to thousand times.. while looking like you're summoning a demon of course) and if you can't find something in the JS Scripting Reference this function probably doesn't exist in the DOM: sometimes AM is the only solution. Simply wrap the ugly code in a function and hide it somewhere. Or make your own DOM.

```
changeTransparencyShapesLayer(false)

function changeTransparencyShapesLayer(value)
{
  var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
  var ref = new ActionReference();
  ref.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt'));
  desc.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref);
  var descOption = new ActionDescriptor();
  descOption.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID('transparencyShapesLayer'), value);
  desc.putObject(charIDToTypeID('T   '), charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), descOption);
  executeAction(charIDToTypeID('setd'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
}
```

Comment: Well what I meant was calling an Action from the Action panel in Photoshop and by JSX I meant jsx files, but it seems like a Photoshop DOM all right.
Anyway your code works perfectly, I tried to decode but can't figure out how you come with 'Lyr  ' or 'Ordn' and so on... If you could enlighten me that would be great.
Anyway thank you for your piece of code Sergey, that's perfect.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood what you've meant. Action Manager code is a representation of Actions in JS. It's difficult to read, but unfortunately it can do much more than understandable DOM

Comment: To start getting code in it, download Scriptlistener plugin from Adobe site: this will start to output most of the things you do in Photoshop as AM code to your desktop. There's also ActionToJavascript converter you can find (sorry can't find the link atm: I'm on a bus)

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I'm gonna check this out!
Thanks again for your help, best

Comment: So, some links: standalone [ActionToJavascript](https://github.com/Hennamann/CEP-Toolkit/tree/master/JSX%20Utility%20Scripts) scripts, originally those are from [xtools by xbytor](http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html) which has _a lot_ of different functions.

Comment: Ok great! I guess this opens up to some new possibilities! Thanks for the help Sergey, best.